# Realization of the possibility "Step Back"

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to implement the ability to step back / forward in the application. 
Thought about this: there is some array that references to functions and to step back / forward, you just need to call the last element in the array. 
Class Manager:

```
public class Manager
[...]
private static var _forward:Vector.<Function>;
[...]

 public static function set forward(f:Function):void{
            _forward.push(f);
}
public static function get forward():Function{
    return _forward[_forward.length-1];
}
```

Use in another class :

```
 [... ]
 Manager.forward = _map.moveObject (mo, 0 , 150, -150 );
 [... ]
```

Such use is causing the error .
Is it the correct idea and implementation ? If not, how can I fix this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn`t work because

```
_map.moveObject(mo, 0, 150, -150);
```

returns not function, but the result of the function (in this case, apparently void). To get a reference to a function to do so:

```
Manager.forward = _map.moveObject;
```

It is now clear that in addition to the functions and parameters of the need (and their number may vary), and also have to store. Generally this problem is solved with the use of pattern Command. About with this interface:

```
    package
    {
    public interface ICommand
    {
            function execute():*;
            function undo():void;
            function redo();
    }
    }
```